# PHP number format using printf

Tags: php, c, printing, format

I write the following php piece of code

```
for ( $i=0 ; $i < sizeof($data) ; $i++ ){
    if ( $i%8 == 0 )
         printf("<br>/* %06x */", $i);
}
```

At each iteration it checks if a multiple of 8 is reached and then it prints the number in its hexadecimal format, for example:

```
i=8 => 000008
```

Although the number is well formatted, i would like to prints it in the following formats : 0x0008.
I found on the web a C piece of in which the printf function is as follows:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("\n/* %0#6x */", i);
}
```

The difference between these two codes is the # character which it does not work in php. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Just append `0x` in front. Don't compare apples to oranges.

Comment: To be clear `"\n/* 0x%04x */"` or beter, IMO, `"\n/* 0x%04X */"`.  Note that `%0#6x` does not print a leading `"0x"` when `i==0`,